# Django messages: how can i change message text in html?

Tags: python, django, django-messages

View:

```
messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Cells marked incorrectly.')
```

HTML:

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
                <li class="{{ message.tags }}">
                {{ message }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Problem: I need to remove marker which you can see on the related [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbKOu.png). I read so many documentation and forums and find nothing. Maby somebody faces this problem and can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider a simple html, beacause django template engine in the end gives you something like this:

```
 <ul class="messages-no-bullets">
         <li class="{{ message.tags }}">
            Test1
        </li>
        <li class="{{ message.tags }}">
            Test2
        </li>
    </ul>
```

so using `CSS` you can do this:

```
.messages-no-bullets li{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```